# Using Multiple case When statements

Tags: sql

I have a `Case When` statement working fine:

```
sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,applydtm) = '1'
         then (cast(durationsecsqty as float)/3600)
         else 0
     End
   ) as Sunday
```

but I need to add another `WHEN` when it gets to the `(cast(durationsecsqty as float)/3600)`. At this point if the return result is `0` I want to pull the values from another column, `moneyamt`.

I'm trying to combine this statement with my first one:

```
Case (CAST(durationsecsqty as float)/3600)
     when 0
     then moneyamt
     else (CAST(durationsecsqty as float)/3600)
 end as Sunday
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need this:

```
sum(
    CASE 
        WHEN datepart(dw,applydtm) = '1' 
        then 
            CASE
                WHEN Case (CAST(durationsecsqty as float)/3600) = 0
                THEN moneyamt
                ELSE (CAST(durationsecsqty as float)/3600)
            END (cast(durationsecsqty as float)/3600) 
        else 0 
   End) as Sunday
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You put me on the right track. I had to adjust it a bit but once i did it worked perfectly.                                                              sum(CASE WHEN datepart(dw,tot.applydtm) = '1' 
        THEN 
           CASE 
              WHEN (cast(tot.durationsecsqty as float)/3600) = '0' 
              THEN tot.moneyamt 
              ELSE (cast(tot.durationsecsqty as float)/3600)
           END 
        ELSE 0 
    END) as Sunday,

Comment: glad it worked for you.  If you are happy with the answer, consider accepting via the checkmark on the left. :)